# For $T:X \to X$ a bounded linear operator and $\lambda$ a scalar with $||T|| = |\lambda|$, $T^*x = \bar\lambda x \implies Tx = \lambda x$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Currently doing this for some revision. $X$ is a Hilbert space, $T:X \to X$ a bounded linear operator and $\lambda$ a scalar with $\|T\| = |\lambda|$. If $\exists x \in X$ such that $T^*x = \bar\lambda x$ then $Tx = \lambda x$.

The question gives a hint to use Cauchy-Schwartz and to consider $<Tx,x>$. The only things I have been able to get are that $|\langle Tx,x\rangle| \le \|Tx\|\|x\| \le \|T\|\|x\|^2 = |\lambda|\|x\|^2$. I'm really unsure how to proceed on this to be honest; any hints would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $\forall x$ or $\exists x$

Comment: I mean $\exists$, will edit this in now @JJR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, so good. But when is this equality actually an equality? We have that $|\langle Tx,x\rangle|\le\|Tx\|\|x\|$ with equality if and only if $Tx$ and $x$ are scalar multiples of each other, so either $x=0$ or $Tx=\alpha x$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb C$. We can reject the first possibility since $T^*x\neq0$. Now use $\langle Tx,y\rangle=\langle x,T^*y\rangle$ and see if you can conclude.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. So we know $Tx = \alpha x$ iff $|<Tx,x>|=||Tx||||x||$. We have $<Tx,x>|≤||Tx||||x||$, and I have now shown $<Tx,x>|≥||Tx||||x||$, which gives the required equality. The only thing I am now unsure of, is how do I know that $Tx=\lambda x$, as opposed to just $\alpha x$?

Comment: Never mind, I have figured this out now. Thanks!

Comment: @elDin0 can you post your proof?

Comment: @JJR Since $\langle Tx,x\rangle=\langle x,T^*x\rangle=\langle x,\bar\lambda x\rangle=\lambda\|x\|^2$, equality holds in Cauchy-Schwarz and so $\alpha\|x\|^2=\langle Tx,x\rangle=\lambda\|x\|^2$.